Verification of alternative matrix calculation in Ledoit-Wolf shrinkage
I've recently been digging into Ledoit-Wolf shrinkage, described in this paper. I don't think familiarity with the technique is strictly necessary, as the issue I'm encountering is with replicating how the calculation is done in the Python package scikit-learn see here. Specifically there is a (probably) equivalent formulation of the linear algebra computation that I do not understand.
Setup:

Let $X$ be a $T\times N$ matrix of observations;
$S = \frac{1}{T}X^TX$ be the sample covariance matrix;
$x_t$ denote the $t$-th row of $X$ arranged as an $N\times 1$ vector such that it holds that $$S = \frac{1}{T}X^TX= \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T x_tx_t^T$$
$||A||^2_F=\frac{1}{N}\mathrm{tr}(A^TA)$ the squared (pseudo-)Frobenius norm for $N\times N$ matrices

Then Ledoit-Wolf suggests calculating the constant
$$\tilde\beta = \frac{1}{T^2} \sum_{t=1}^T||x_tx_t^T-S||^2_F$$
I can run this calculation, and it matches up with expectations from scikit-learn's implementation. However, they calculate this quantity in a different and (probably) more efficient way. Define the matrix $A$ as
$$A = \frac{1}{T}Y^TY-S^2$$
where $Y$ is the element-wise square of entries in the matrix $X$, i.e. $y_{ij} = x_{ij}^2$, and similar for $S^2$. Then calculate
$$
\tilde\beta = \frac{1}{NT}\sum_i^N\sum_j^N a_{ij}
$$
I'm struggling to verify that this holds in the general case; I keep getting lost in a sea of variables, and have very little intuition about what $\mathrm{tr}((x_tx_t^T-S)^T(x_tx_t^T-S))$ should look like.
Any help is appreciated

@user8675309 I was trying to follow the notation of the linked paper, but I have edited for clarity. I hope that helps you address the substance of the question.

Let
$$
\mathbf{S}
= \frac{1}{T} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X}
= \frac{1}{T}
\sum_t \mathbf{x}_t \mathbf{x}_t^T
$$
In the following, we use
$\lVert \mathbf{A} \rVert_F^2
= \mathbf{A}:\mathbf{A}
= \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A})$.
Note this definition is somehow different from what you wrote originally. But you can easily accommodate this.
It holds
\begin{eqnarray}
T\cdot \beta &\doteq &
\sum_t
\lVert \mathbf{x}_t \mathbf{x}_t^T-\mathbf{S} \rVert_F^2 \\
&=&
\sum_t
\left( \mathbf{x}_t \mathbf{x}_t^T-\mathbf{S} \right)
:
\left( \mathbf{x}_t \mathbf{x}_t^T-\mathbf{S} \right) \\
&=&
\sum_t
\lVert \mathbf{x}_t \rVert^4
+
T \lVert \mathbf{S} \rVert_F^2
-
2
(\sum_t \mathbf{x}_t \mathbf{x}_t^T)
: \mathbf{S} \\
&=&
\sum_t
\lVert \mathbf{x}_t \rVert^4
-
T \lVert \mathbf{S} \rVert_F^2
\end{eqnarray}
Consider a matrix $\mathbf{Y}$ with elements
$Y_{tn}=X_{tn}^2$.
We have
$$
\mathbf{C}
=\mathbf{Y}^T \mathbf{Y}
= \sum_t \mathbf{y}_t \mathbf{y}_t^T
$$
with elements
\begin{eqnarray}
C_{ij}
&=&
\sum_t Y_{ti} Y_{tj}
=\sum_t X_{ti}^2 X_{tj}^2 \\
\sum_{ij}C_{ij}
&=&
\sum_t \sum_{ij} X_{ti}^2 X_{tj}^2
=\sum_t (\sum_{i} X_{ti}^2)
(\sum_j X_{tj}^2)
=\sum_t 
\lVert \mathbf{x}_t \rVert^2
\lVert \mathbf{x}_t \rVert^2
=\sum_t 
\lVert \mathbf{x}_t \rVert^4
\end{eqnarray}
We deduce
\begin{eqnarray}
T\cdot \beta &=&
\sum_{ij}
\left( C_{ij}-T S_{ij}^2 \right) \\
\beta &=&
\sum_{ij}
\left( \frac{1}{T}C_{ij}- S_{ij}^2 \right)
\end{eqnarray}

Excellent explanation Steph, thank you!
